# adding razor statement in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, razor

Im trying to add some C# code in my javascript. But I can't parse my var name into the C# code.

What I want is this:

```
$.ready(function(){
   var name = $("#input");

   @Class.text(name)
});
```

But it wont allow me to parse the name.

This is a short version of what i got, the @Class represent a more complex function

Comment: Is that all razor code or part javascript?

Comment: its javascript, placed in the header of my cshtml document

Comment: I'm sure you can do the functionallity of text method in javascript, so I think you don't need razor to accomplish it

Comment: You're confusing server side and client side.  C# "spits out" the markup to the browser, including javascript.  Javascript then runs on the client, having no knowledge of the language you're using on the server (C#, PHP, straight HTML, etc).  So what you're trying to do, you cannot do.  What's your goal?  Waht is @Class and what do you want it to do with the name variable?  Is "text" represented here supposed to be the jquery text method?  Do you want the value of $('#input') to be the text of another DOM element?

Comment: @Eli Gassert: What im trying to do, is to have my javascript call a C# method, without refreshing the page. I know that you can do a JSON call, but im just don't know how, so figured that since I'm using cshtml I might be able to call the C# method directly

Comment: There are a lot examples and tutorials of JSON, please search for it before ask

Comment: @Alberto León: It's not that I havent search for tutorials on JSON, it's just that what I've found is not ideal solutions, and I like to check for all solutions, before implementing a lesser perfect one :D

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is indeed incorrect.

The `var name = $("#input");` is javascript. It is executed at the client end after the document is loaded. The `@Class` is server side and is executed when the page is being generated.

You cannot use javascript variables in C#.  What is it that you are trying to achieve; there may be a different way to do so.

--
Update : You are trying to call a c# method from javascript.

Overall this will require a post back to the server - see  http://blog.bobcravens.com/2009/11/ajax-calls-to-asp-net-mvc-action-methods-using-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

@MichaelTotKorsgaard Based on our discussion in the comments of your question, I think I now understand.  Unfortunately what you're trying to do simply won't work.  It doesn't work that way.  The reason you do AJAX/JSON is because, once C#/MVC/ASP.NET returns HTML (it doesn't actually know if what it returns is valid), it's up to the Client to "do stuff" with it.  That's where Javascript comes in.  But the server-side MVC and client-side JS don't actually know anything about each other.  You Need to either 1) post back or 2) use AJAX.

It's time to saddle up and learn how to do it :)

If you give more details about what you're actually trying to accomplish -- like what you're trying to load from JS/AJAX -- then I'm sure SO can give you more information to set you on the right path.